# How do you embed a video into a Google Doc?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

Is it possible to embed a video into a Google document -- not a presentation? If so, how?

Comment: How long is the video? Does it have audio? You can embed an animated gif if you have a short video without any audio.

Comment: It's a short screencast, so that is feasible actually.

Answer (score 2):

Ruben is right. At the moment, you cannot embed a video into a Google Doc. However, based on your comment, for a short screencast without audio you can embed an animated GIF into your document. That should do the job.

Here's an example.

[image: Embed Animated GIF into Google Doc]

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to insert a video in a Google document. Below is the current Insert menu.

[image: Google documents insert menu]

Comment: Nothing with the Script Editor or Insert Drawing? How is this possible in 2016?

Comment: @Emre: I know! Please send your feedback directly to Google. To do so, open a Google document, then click on Help -> Report a problem. Then fill out the form and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

DocentEdu is your answer. 
Go to DocentEdu and install it as an AddOn to your Google Doc.
Once you publish your doc, you should be able to add videos through DocentEdu AddOn.