# How can I get a Google Doc to render HTML?

Tags: google-docs, html

I would like to embed HTML into a Google Doc and have it rendered in place when the Doc is being viewed.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you embed a video into a Google Doc?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91425/how-do-you-embed-a-video-into-a-google-doc)

Comment: Similar, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to [How do you embed a video into a Google Doc?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91425/how-do-you-embed-a-video-into-a-google-doc) with a sligth adaptation:

> At this time it's not possible to <s>insert a video</s> *to embed HTML* in a Google document.
>   Below is the current Insert menu.
>
> [image: Google documents insert menu]

Comment: This answer is pretty useless.